# Read integer from right to left, then do something based on the integer?

Tags: java, binary-data

Currently I have a program that converts from hexadecimal to binary. So, for example, if the user entered `B1` into the program, the output would be `10110001`.

What I want to do is make it so that Java reads the binary number from right to left and then outputs whether the number is a one or a zero. For example, if it's a 1 the program will say "this is a one" and if it's a 0 the program will say "this is a zero".

This may seem pointless but I will be using this to code the movement for a finch robot, i.e. if its a zero move for 3 seconds, if its a one move for 6 seconds.
Thanks!

Comment: Well once you've got the conversion to a string, you're not really "reading" any more... you just need a loop going from `text.length() - 1` to 0, using `charAt` to get one digit at a time. This sounds like a simple `for` loop to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply loop through the number? (as Jon Skeet suggests)

```
//not sure what type your input is, in any case, convert it to a string (or byte array)
String str = "10110001";
for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(str.charAt(i) == '1')
        System.out.println("one");
    if(str.charAt(i) == '0')
        System.out.println("zero");
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 ah yes, I missed that. Fixed it